# Custom location for custom Project template with extension in VS 2017

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I am in the process of upgrading an extension from VS 2015 to VS 2017.
According to [Upgrading Custom Project Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/upgrading-custom-project-and-item-templates-for-visual-studio-2017), they have changed how custom project templates are handled in VS 2017.

I am just rather confused at present. 
Let me explain how our extension worked in VS 2015, then I will explain what I've tried to do in the upgrade.

Our extension is for internal use by technical consultants of our company. It loads bits and pieces of calculations from a database and puts together source files. These source files are loaded into a C# solution which can then be compiled and debugged by the technical consultant and adjusted/rewritten and saved back to the DB as necessary.

The extension has a Tool window, the Tool window allows you to connect to a database, when the database connection is established, a solution is created and the source files (made up form the bits and pieces) loaded.

So our template is a blank Class library project which receives these source files. Let's call it CalcTemplate.zip.
CalcTemplate.zip was included in the Extension project, simply as an added file.

```
     csTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate("CalcTemplate.zip", "CSharp");
     // Create a new C# Class Library project using the template obtained above.
     soln.AddFromTemplate(templatePath, prjPath, "CalcProject", false);
```

However, it was not installed by the vsix, but by the msi that installs the rest of the software necessary for the program.
So our users (the technical consultants) never pick the template from the 
File -> New -> Project option.

As explained in this post: [Creating custom project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates) 
I have added the template as a new project to the solution which includes the Extension, and also added it as an asset to the Extension project. I can choose it as a New Project in the experimental instance of VS, but it is of no use in our scenario.

So how the Extension is supposed to work, is to find the CalcTemplate.zip file in the folder of the directory where the software is installed, let's say

> C:\Program Files\SoftwareName\Custom Templates\

and then use the template when  building the solution. Please note that the extension is useless without first installing the rest of the software, so the zip file will reside in the path as mentioned above after using a separate msi installation.

When I debug the Extension in the experimental instance (or if I install the vsix and test the functionality) it can't find the template which is located in

> "C:\Program Files\SoftwareName\Custom Templates\"

There is a runtime error at

```
csTemplatePath = soln.GetProjectTemplate("CalcTemplate.zip", "CSharp");
```

I have changed the folder in Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> User Project templates location to point to the above mentioned path.

According to the first link above, I also need to change the .vstemplate file and create a .vstman file.

Here is my .vstemplate file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Project" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" 
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate-
sdkextension/2010">
<TemplateData>
<Name>CalcTemplate</Name>
<Description>CalcTemplate</Description>
<Icon>CalcTemplate.ico</Icon>
<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
<RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
<SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
<TemplateID>6f47c81e-6f6d-433f-8203-0bd0857765bd</TemplateID>
<CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
<DefaultName>CalcTemplate</DefaultName>
<ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
</TemplateData>
<TemplateContent>
<Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
  <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" 
TargetFileName="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs">AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>      
</Project>
</TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Here is my .vstman file:

```
<VSTemplateManifest Version="1.0" Locale="1033" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplatemanifest/2015">  
<VSTemplateContainer TemplateType="Project">  
<RelativePathOnDisk>C:\Program Files\SoftwareName\Custom User Project Templates\CalcTemplate</RelativePathOnDisk>  
<TemplateFileName>CalcTemplate.vstemplate</TemplateFileName>  
<VSTemplateHeader>  
  <TemplateData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">  
    <Name>CalcTemplate</Name>  
    <Description>CalcTemplate</Description>  
    <Icon>CalcTemplate.ico</Icon>  
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>  
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>2.0</RequiredFrameworkVersion>  
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>  
    <TemplateID>6f47c81e-6f6d-433f-8203-0bd0857765bd</TemplateID>  
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>  
    <DefaultName>CalcTemplate</DefaultName>  
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>  
  </TemplateData>  
</VSTemplateHeader>  
</VSTemplateContainer>  
</VSTemplateManifest>
```

So my question is, how do I get VS 2017 to pick up the template in the folder
"C:\Program Files\SoftwareName\Custom Templates\" during runtime? 
Perhaps it is obvious. I'm just confused at present.

Comment: I create a console template via vs2017, then create a command menu to create a project via solution2.AddFromTemplate, which works fine, because i would suggest that you could create a vs2017 template and compare related file. then generate the same files with vs2017's template

Comment: I eventually just moved where I install the custom project template to %USERPROFILE%\Documents\\My Exported Templates\.